# Missing Google Analytics Accounts from GA iOS app?

Tags: google-analytics

I have 26 website tracking codes currently directly under my Google Analytics account, plus a large handful of shared access accounts (roughly 40 total accounts combined).

The last 4 or 5 direct accounts that I've added are not showing up through the GA iOS app.  They show up fine through GA in the browser, but no reference whatsoever in the iOS app.

I've tried deleting and reinstalling the app.

Any ideas what might be going on here and how to get the data to show up on the iOS side?

I've been Googling all morning and have been having a hard time finding the right search to find anything relevant.  It's not like I'm doing much, if any work from the iOS app, but it's helpful to be able to pull sites up for a quick glance.

Comment: Did they ever show up? A new account I created isn't showing in the app yet. It's been about 12 hours

Comment: @ElanHasson They did eventually show up, but it wasn't a period of hours... more like days.  I never came up with a resolution...  tried installing and uninstalling a few times.  

Long story short, it's fixed, but I can't tell you why on my end =/.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I see the older sites I have, but the new one doesn't show up.  I guess I'll wait and see.